# How to write a program that runs another GUI program inside it

Tags: windows, launcher

I am not sure how to ask the question so here is a picture of some idea that came to mind

[image: pic]

So for example, when you run my "custom launcher" it displays a window with a couple buttons on the side which you can assign values to. When you click on a button, the appropriate program will run in the big panel on the right (in window mode).

This is all from the user's perspective of course. They will just see that the program they want to run appears in that panel. The actual implementation may have nothing to do with "one program  running inside another program"

My own use case is limited to windows desktop platforms only, but if it is possible to generalize it that would be nice as well.

Is this actually possible? Can I write such a program that will run another program inside a panel? The program that's launched may be someone else's, such as MS paint or calculator.

Comment: Only way that I can think would involve you writing a custom display driver.. Can you expand a bit on what you're trying to achieve? there is probably an easier approach. [ie. why do programs need to be inside a panel]

Comment: I would like to create a launcher application that basically has a logo on top, with the actual program that it has been programmed to launch running in a panel. The program may be arbitrary. I have not thought of anything useful that could come from this idea, but the idea seems amusing. I mean, I *could* just place shortcuts on the desktop and let the OS handle running the programs, but it's missing the logo!

Comment: Sounds like what you're looking for is Remote Desktop Services, previously known as Terminal Services.

Comment: I think whatever you end up with will be a very large hack - Windows isn't designed to let you do this. A couple of creative approaches to think about 1) run it as a background user and try to bitblt the screen across 2) run it as a normal program, but intercept all windows messages to that program with PeekMessage. intercept and block any message that attempts to move/resize/max/min the window etc. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644943(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Doesn't seem like a good idea in that case. I'd probably settle with a similar launcher idea, except instead of running the program inside it, just do what other launchers do and let windows handle the program execution. Then it's just a regular launcher application (is that a term?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to expand on my comment above, here is an approach that may work for you: **Fake it** :)

When you launch the program, intercept all windows messages to the program that control it's position on screen. That way it 'appears' to be fixed in place, but in reality it's still attached to the normal Windows desktop.

Here's some light reading for you:

[Windows Event Hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> A hook is a mechanism by which an application can intercept events,
>   such as messages, mouse actions, and keystrokes. A function that
>   intercepts a particular type of event is known as a hook procedure. A
>   hook procedure can act on each event it receives, and then modify or
>   discard the event.

Comment: There's no need to subclass the window.  Just set its position and remove the resizable window style.  If you move your launcher window you move the launchee window as well.

Comment: The hooks are pretty interesting. I could probably use them in other ideas. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @Dan-o agreed. There is no need to subclass the window. This can all be done from a completely separate app (the launcher).

Comment: Subclassing is a term from the 90s that meant to hook another window's messages - usually via SetWindowLong and GWL_WNDPROC.  It's got a different meaning in OO programming.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend against it in a commercial application because you are modifying the behavior of software you don't own - that software may make assumptions about what its parent window is, but for experimentation there's the [SetParent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Win32 function.